# Calculating total hours worked

Tags: worksheet-function

Calculate the total hours worked on the first day, which is equal to the difference between cell F6 and cell E6 multiplied by 24.  What is the formula?

Comment: it's `(E6-F6)*24`

Comment: Welcome to Super User, but please don't ask us to do your homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

As Jasen said in his comment, it's simply
`=(E6-F6)*24`